# How to create a code block with boxed title at top (see image)?

Tags: code, terminal-output

How do I create something that look like this? *(Taken from [FEniCS Tutorial](https://fenicsproject.org/tutorial/) book pdf page 14 (actual 6))*

It doesn't have a caption or table/figure tag near it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy to solve with the `fancyvrb` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Terminal}{Verbatim}{
frame=lines,
framesep=4mm,
label=\fbox{\small\ttfamily Terminal}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{Terminal}
Terminal> curl -s https://get.fenicsproject.org | bash
\end{Terminal}

\end{document}
```

[image]